# how to send stream files to grpc and get response in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

hi i have 2 problem with grpc

1. how i can send list from client to grpc server

image of code in client side :
[image]

code client side :

```
 var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
        var client = new FileOperation.FileOperationClient(channel);
        var input = new OperationRequest
        {
            Title = "Test",
            ListOfStrings = new List<string>()
        { "F:\\Images\\1.jpg", "F:\\Images\\2.jpg", "F:\\Images\\3.jpg" }
        };
```

code of .proto file in grpc server:

```
    syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Server";


service FileOperation {
  rpc SendFileOperation (stream OperationRequest) returns (stream OperationResponse);
}

message OperationRequest {
    string title=1;
    repeated ListOfStrings listOfStrings=2;
}

message ListOfStrings {
    repeated string strings=1;
}

message OperationResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

2.how i can send paths to grpc server with stream(send first and get response ,then send second ,...)

Answer (score 0):

Repeated fields have some additional restrictions in protobufs that cause this challenge in several of the language implementations.

In C# you should be able to achieve what you want using `Add` ([link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-)).

IIUC your second question correctly, you cannot because the streams are independent.

You could...

- either annotate messages with an identifier so you can identify individual messages uniquely within the stream;
- or tie specific requests to their responses (`rpc SendFileOperation (OperationRequest) returns (OperationResponse)`